# Limiting the number of visible rows in a menu: JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to limit the number of visible rows for a menu in JavaFX?

Here is a working example

```
public class MenuProb extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 800, 600);
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu someValues = new Menu("Values");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Value " + i);
            someValues.getItems().add(item);
        }

        menuBar.getMenus().add(someValues);
        group.getChildren().addAll(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

When the above code is run, a menu is created wherein the scrollbar appears only after the menuitems have exceeded the screen height.

[image]

Is there a way to limit the number of visible rows to a pre-decided number? That is, a scrollbar appears if the number of rows exceeds that limit.

Comment: Maybe **menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());** could help your case, but you can surely try http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0560__JavaFX_Menu.htm for more help

Comment: I'm kind of curious. If you want to limit the amount of rows being displayed, then is there a purpose as to why you would have more items than what can be displayed in the first place?

Comment: @A.Cucci, if I add, say 50 elements in the menu, only 29 elements are "visible" on the screen, but the rest can be accessed by scrolling up or down.

Comment: Can you use a `CustomMenuItem` with the desired `Control`?

Comment: I think there is no way to achieve that except writing your own `Menu` Library unfortunately! I've been trying all the day to limit the number of rows but no luck yet! `JavaFX` gives us no much deep control over the structure!

Comment: @trashgod, I don't think so. From what I understand from its documentation, it is used to embed arbitrary nodes within a menu such as sliders, checkboxes etc.

Comment: @Yahya, I believe that's the case too. It's quite unfortunate. I'll wait for a few more days, and if there is no positive response by then, I might end up writing my own `Menu` library, as you suggested.

Comment: I've suggested an approach [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816084/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use a [`CustomMenuItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html) with a [`Control`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) that lets you adjust the size. The example below illustrates a [`ComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html), which allows `setVisibleRowCount()`, and a [`ListView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html), which includes a `prefWidthProperty` and `prefHeightProperty`.

[image: combo]

[image: list]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44792148/230513 */
public class CustomMenuTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 320, 240);

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            comboBox.getItems().add("Value " + i);
        }
        CustomMenuItem comboMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(comboBox, false);
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        comboBox.setVisibleRowCount(16);

        ObservableList<String> values = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            values.add("Value " + i);
        }
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(values);
        CustomMenuItem listMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(listView, false);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu comboMenu = new Menu("Combo Values");
        comboMenu.getItems().add(comboMenuItem);
        Menu listMenu = new Menu("List Values");
        listMenu.getItems().add(listMenuItem);
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(comboMenu, listMenu);
        group.getChildren().addAll(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! That looks interesting! I had no idea about the existence of `ListView`! By fiddling with some css, I should be able to make the `listMenu` resemble the original one.