# Is there an equivalent for ComboBoxModel in swing for javafx?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, combobox

The old version of the system uses swing ComboBoxModel. I am converting it to javafx. Is there any equivalent in javafx? Thanks.

Comment: The `ComboBox` model is an `ObservableList<T>`, but you may be looking for the control's `SelectionModel`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816084/230513).

Comment: You should start by having a look at [JavaFX, using UI Controls, Combo Box](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html)